# A List of URL to ImageView?

Tags: android

I want to shows the images in imageview from an array list,the array containing a list of URL like

```
private String imageUrls[] = {"http://theopentutorials.com/totwp331/wp-content/uploads/totlogo.png",
                            "http://theopentutorials.com/totwp331/wp-content/uploads/totlogo.png",
                            "http://theopentutorials.com/totwp331/wp-content/uploads/totlogo.png"
                            };
```

When i go to next image it shows it shows the `OutOfMemoryException`.

Please help

I used the code as follows

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
              Bitmap bitmap = null;
              try {



          String url = urls[0];

                InputStream in = null;
                try {
                    in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);


              } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                  Log.e("MyApp", e.getMessage());
              }
              return bitmap;  
          }

          protected void onPostExecute(final Bitmap result) {
              handler=new Handler();
              handler.post(new Runnable() { 
                    @Override 
                    public void run() { 

                         bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);

                    } 
                }); 

          }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864168/getting-this-exception-which-forces-the-android-app-to-crash-on-start/33864558#33864558

Comment: the images are to big

Comment: Use largeHeap in manifest, but take a look at your image sizes...

Comment: yes,bt i need to display the image.Is there any way to handle this exception?Please help

Comment: Take a look at Picasso library http://square.github.io/picasso/ Don't try to download/cache/display images yourself unless it's really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There's a dedicated page on the android developer website about this topic:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

> To avoid java.lang.OutOfMemory exceptions, check the dimensions of a
>   bitmap before decoding it, unless you absolutely trust the source to
>   provide you with predictably sized image data that comfortably fits
>   within the available memory.

Answer (score 0):

Bitmaps in Android can be a minefield for errors like this. You would save a large amount of time by using a well structured and well tested library to perform this task for you.

[Picasso for example](http://square.github.io/picasso/), is extremely good.

In your case:

```
imageUrls[] = {"http://theopentutorials.com/totwp331/wp-content/uploads/totlogo.png",
                            "http://theopentutorials.com/totwp331/wp-content/uploads/totlogo.png",
                            "http://theopentutorials.com/totwp331/wp-content/uploads/totlogo.png"
                            };

Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrls[index]).into(bmImage);
```

Comment: Its working but only the first image is displayed other two is not shown

Comment: The images are all the same. You probably don't notice the difference.

Comment: No sir,  i tried the different urls.the imageview shows as white screen

Answer (score 0):

I had similar usecase where I had to download bunch of pics from external URL and show them in single activity. As explained by @Aashvi's link the comments, images take up 4*imageheight*imageWidth about of bytes.. So I started loading thumbnails of it. (of maximum height 300 along with maintaining the aspect ratio).
I am pasting here code from my project in which asynctask gets images and makes smaller bitmap of it and sets on imageview  and references used.

```
   protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

     Bitmap mPic = null;
    try {

        mPic = CommonUtils.getThumbnailFromUrl(urldisplay);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
 }
```

Here is the implementation of getThumbNailFromUrl

```
public static Bitmap getThumbnailFromUrl(String url) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream input;
    try {
        input = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();

        if (input != null) {
            BitmapFactory.Options onlyBoundsOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            onlyBoundsOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            onlyBoundsOptions.inDither = true;//optional
            onlyBoundsOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;//optional
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, onlyBoundsOptions);

            input.close();
            if ((onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth == -1) || (onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight == -1))
                return null;

            int originalSize = (onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight > onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth) ? onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight : onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth;

            double ratio = (originalSize > 300) ? (originalSize / 300) : 1.0;

            BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = getPowerOfTwoForSampleRatio(ratio);
            bitmapOptions.inDither = true;//optional
            bitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;//optional
            input = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, bitmapOptions);
            assert input != null;
            input.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;

}
```

This code has been taken from following stackoverflow answer. 
[How to get Bitmap from an Uri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879992/get-bitmap-from-an-uri-android)

Hope this helps.